# Name clashes in Python modules

Tags: python, name-clash

I have this problem for homework:

> For module1, module2, and the client module shown below, indicate which of the imported identifiers would result in a name clash if the imported identifiers were not fully qualified.

[image]

I answered:
`func_2` clashes between `module2` and `module3`
`func_3` clashes between `module2` and `main`

However, the answer listed in the text is just
`func_3`.
Am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Please copy the 3 examples from that image right there into your question.

Comment: And you're correct, and the text is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Antti. I tried to import the image, but when I posted, it changed to the link. I'm new here. Isn't there a way to preview posts?  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not the image but write the code in image by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In module1, there is no name clash, because module1 does not know that module2 and client module exist.  module2 does not know that module1 and client module exist.  client module, however, imports module1 and module2.  Therefore, it has defined func_1 once (in module1), func_2 twice (in module1 and module2), and func_3 twice (in module2 and client module).  For illustration, I'll write two files: main_module and imported_module.

imported_module looks like this:

```
x = True
print 'x in imported_module: %s' % ('x' in locals())
print 'y in imported_module: %s' % ('y' in locals())
```

main_module looks like this:

```
y = True
from imported_module import *
print "" # put a blank line between what imported_module prints and what
         # main_module prints
print 'y in main_module: %s' % ('y' in locals())
print 'x in main_module: %s' % ('x' in locals())
```

The result of running main_module:

```
y in imported_module: False
x in imported_module: True

y in main_module: True
x in main_module: True
```

main_module has both variables, because it defined y and imported x.  imported_module has x, because it defined it, but it does not have y.

Comment: Thanks zondo. That's very helpful.